# How to write a compiler in Haskell? In C# I use a lot of state

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, state

I'm doing a compiler in C# for a school project and I can't stop wondering how I would do *that* in Haskell.

For example:

My code generation for a While loop is:

```
public override void generateCode(Compiler compiler)
    {
        int jumpToTheBeginningInstructionIndex = compiler.getIndexOfNextActionInCurrentFunction();
        MachineInstructions.JMP jumpTotheBeginning = new MachineInstructions.JMP(jumpToTheBeginningInstructionIndex);
        MachineInstructions.JMPF jumpToTheEnd = new MachineInstructions.JMPF();

        booleanExpression.generateCode(compiler);

        //I insert the jump to the end here:
        compiler.addAction(jumpToTheEnd);

        foreach(IAction action in this.thenActions)
        {
            action.generateCode(compiler);
        }
        compiler.addAction(jumpTotheBeginning);

        //...But is here where I know where should it jump to:
        jumpToTheEnd.whereToJump = compiler.getIndexOfNextActionInCurrentFunction();
    }
```

You can see how I insert the code for the jumpToTheEnd at the very middle of the method, but is not until the end where I know the line where the jump jumps. Fortunately, I keep a pointer to that jump and I'm easily able to set its whereToJump attribute at the very end of the method.

How would you do that in Haskell!?
Any *recommended* tutorial?

Comment: One simple method is to build a structured table of functions and then call them in order (exploting the HOFs).

Comment: Here's some reading that might interest you http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours

Comment: @PedroRodrigues That's an interpeter and so lacks the code-gen phase, which is the subject of the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dunno. I'm not sure you'd want to structure the code-gen phase quite like this in Haskell. But under the assumption that you did, one thing you can do is put your labels in a lazy state monad and [tie the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) using `mfix`.

Here's a complete runnable example of this technique. We'll have a simple AST with just while-loops and statements that don't do anything; and a simple instruction type with just labels, jumps, and statements that don't do anything. Our compiler will maintain the latest-allocated label in some state. Then I guess your question is how to generate "forward" jumps to labels that haven't been allocated yet.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer

data Instruction = Nop | Jump Int | Label Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
data AST = While AST AST | Rest               deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
type Compiler = StateT Int (Writer [Instruction])

generateLabel :: Compiler Int
generateLabel = do
    v <- get
    put (v+1)
    tell [Label v]
    return v

compile :: AST -> Compiler ()
compile Rest = tell [Nop]
compile (While b c) = do
    start <- generateLabel
    compile b
    mfix $ \end -> do
        tell [Jump end] -- here we generate a forward jump
        compile c
        tell [Jump start]
        generateLabel   -- here we allocate the label we're forward-jumping to
    return ()

runCompiler :: Compiler () -> [Instruction]
runCompiler = execWriter . flip evalStateT 0
```

In ghci, try for example `runCompiler (compile (While Rest Rest))` for the simplest example.